# Directed Acyclic Hierarchical Graph Implementation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

I need to display a acyclic directed graph looking somewhat like this:

[image]

I created a nested hierarchical Data Structure similar to this:

```
[
 {
  node: 'abs'
  children: [
   {
    node: 'jhg',
    children: [{...}]
   {
    node: 'AAA',
    children: [{...}]
   },
 {
  node: 'fer'
  children: [
   {
    node: 'AAA',
    children: [{...}]
   {
    node: 'xcv',
    children: [{...}]
   },
 {
]
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to actually display the data since the nodes with multiple parents and their children would appear multiple times, but I had no other idea how to handle it yet.

I simply want to render those nodes to an imaginary grid. Therefore i need to parse my data structure and set their grid values. The problem is i dont know how to parse the data structure with hierarchy logic.

What I am doing right now is obviously causing problems for nodes with multiple parents:

```
for (const root of allRoots) {
  currentLevel = 0;
  if (root.node === 'VB8') {
    getChildrenTree(root);
  }
}

function getChildrenTree(node) {
  currentLevel++;
  node._gridX = currentLevel;

  if (node.children.length > 0) {
    for(const nextChild of children ) {
      getChildrenTree(nextChild);
    }
  }
```

The Problem with this code is that it will only run through one path and then stop when there arent any children.

I just need an algorithm which runs through the tree and sets each nodes hierarchy level.

I hope that this is not too confusing.

Comment: What exactly is `getChildrenTree` supposed to return?

Comment: Actually it is not returning anything. I just use it to set the gridX value for now. The return is not in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reference the same node from two separate parents, you shouldn't define it more than once. I suggest listing all nodes in a flat array with a single 'invisible' root node and referencing children by id or array index:

```
[
 {id: 0, name: "root", children: [1, 2]},
 {id: 1, name: "abs", children: [3, 4]},
 {id: 2, name: "fer", children: [5, 6]},
 {id: 3, name: "jhg", children: [...]},
 {id: 4, name: "AAA", children: [...]},
 ...
]
```

then you can recursively set their tree depths like so:

```js
function setDepth(node, depth) {
  if (node._gridX && node._gridX >= depth) {
    // node has been visited already through a path of greater or equal length
    // so tree depths wouldn't change
    return
  }
  node._gridX = depth
  node.children
    .map(idx => nodeArray[idx]) // get the actual objects from indices
    .forEach(child => setDepth(child, depth+1))
}
setDepth(nodeArray[0], 0) // start at root
```

... careful though, as this algorithm will get stuck in a loop if your nodes have any cycles

Comment: I suspected that something like that would make more sense. Thank you very much for the input. I will try it out right away.

Comment: Yes this is absolutely working as intended. Thank you very much